Would a Particle being attracted to a particle that is repulsed by it break the laws of thermodynamics?
Working on an idea for a magic system in my writing but I want to know what would actually happen if this was a thing.
Let's say we have particle A and particle B.
Particle A is attracted to particle B, so it "wants" to go to particle B.
Particle B is repulsed by Particle A, so it "wants" to go away from Particle A.
Would there be an equilibrium of distance? Would A chase B forever causing a perpetual motion machine? Does this even make sense, since all movement is relative?

This would lead to infinite acceleration and therefore infinite kinetic energy of both particles, seemingly coming from nowhere.

I think you're going to have to specify, at a minimum, the relative strengths of the attractive and repulsive forces, and how they  vary with distance.

Imaginarily, this situation would violate lots of laws, at very first, Newton's 3rd law, Next, Infinite energy out of nowhere and so on. Maybe this question is off-topic.

This is an active field of research in non equilibrium statistical mechanics. You might want to look for odd elasticity and non reciprocal interactions in active matter. Basically, you obtain chasing motion with solitons, travelling waves, phase separations...

but yes it violates the basic law of equilibrium thermodynamic. Here you are in the real of non equilibrium statistical mechanics (one might even say non equilibrium thermodynamics, but the thermodynzmics of such system is not often well defined) and a lot more is allowed

It would violate the law of action and reaction and conservation of momentum.

Unless one particle has positive inertial mass and the other has negative inertial mass, and the attraction/repulsion in the question meant acceleration instead of force.

Very perceptive of you. You pass the test. :) However, normally one assumes the mass is non-negative; and it is with respect to that back-drop that the answer is posed.

Suppose the positions of the objects, as functions of time, are $s_1(t)$ and $s_2(t)$.  Suppose $s_1(0)<s_2(0)$.  Suppose object 1 repels object 2 with force $F(s_2-s_1)$ and object 2 attracts object 1 with force $G(s_2-s1)$.  Then the system is governed by the differential equations
$$s_1''=G(s_2-s_1)\qquad s_2''=F(s2-s1)$$
You can try making different assumptions about $F$ and $G$ and working out how the system behaves.

If both particles have positive mass, this would violate the conservation of momentum.
However, in 1957 Hermann Bondi speculated about what would happen if you had particles of negative mass. In this case, the acceleration would be in the opposite direction to the force, so a pair of particles with one mass positive and one negative with an attractive or repulsive force between them would undergo 'runaway motion' where both particles would accelerate in the same direction. This doesn't violate conservation of momentum, because the masses cancel out and the net mass (and hence momentum, kinetic energy, etc.) of the pair is zero.
Of course, no negative-mass particles are known, and it is widely assumed that none are possible.
See:
Bondi, H. (1957). "Negative Mass in General Relativity". Reviews of Modern Physics. 29 (3): 423–428.
Forward, R. L. (1990). "Negative matter propulsion". Journal of Propulsion and Power. 6: 28–37.

First of all such, such a system would violate Newton's third law:
For any to Bodies $A$ and $B$, let $\vec F_{AB}$ be the the force $A$ is acting on $B$ and $\vec F_{BA}$ be the force $B$ is acting on $A$. Then Newton's third law sates that
$$\vec F_{AB} = - \vec F_{BA}$$
This means, if $A$ is attracted/repulsed to $B$, $B$ is attracted/repulsed to $A$.
So the situation you are describing is rather unphysical.
Nontheless it is of course possible to the behaviour of the second order differential equation in this situation. An example for the situation that you described could be:
$$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \vec X_A := Gm_B \nabla_{X_A} \frac{1}{|\vec X_A- \vec X_B|^3}
$$,
and
$$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \vec X_B := - Gm_A \nabla_{X_B} \frac{1}{|\vec X_A- \vec X_B|^3}
$$.
Note, that the additional $-$ in the second equation is unphysical. It describes, that Particle $B$ is repulsed by $A$. In this situation, as @Marius Ladegård Meyer commented, the particles would accelerate infinitely (but not needily in finite time) in one direction.
The situation changes if $A$ wanting to go to $B$ and $B$ wanting to go away from $A$ is interpreted a first order statement. I.e., not the acceleration but the velocities are determined by the equation. An example could be
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \vec X_A := - \frac{\vec X_A- \vec X_B}{|\vec X_A- \vec X_B|}
$$,
and
$$ \frac{d^2}{dt} \vec X_B := - \frac{\vec X_A- \vec X_B}{|\vec X_A- \vec X_B|}
$$.
In this scenario $A$ and $B$ would move with constant distance in the same direction. But, $B$ was fleeing from.
There are more complicated differential equations, e.g. to describe the movement of predator and prey in biology.
But as said before, these are not fundamental physical laws of motion, but for example effective equations to describe the behaviour of animals.
